# Read a nodejs buffer byte per byte

Tags: node.js

Let suppose I have a following buffer:

```
const buf1 = Buffer.from('12ADFF1345', 'hex');
```

How I can read all the bytes contained in it in order to process them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method:

```javascript
const readBufferBytes = (buffer, callback, index=0) => {
  if(!Buffer.isBuffer(buffer)) return callback(new Error('Invalid value for buffer has been provided'));
  if (typeof callback !== 'function') return callback(new Error('The callback is not a function'));
  try {
    callback(null, buffer.readUInt8(index));
    // We iterate the buffer as an array that each array posision is a byte length.
    return readBufferBytes(buffer,callback,index+1);
  } catch(e) {
     return callback(e);
  }
}
```

I use recursion in order to read each byte and via a callback I return the value. Also it ca be made asyncronous as well:

```
const readBufferBytes = (buffer, callback, index=0) => {
  if(!Buffer.isBuffer(buffer)) return callback(new Error('Invalid value for buffer has been provided'));
  if (typeof callback !== 'function') return callback(new Error('The callback is not a function'));

  try {
    return process.nextTick(()=>{
        callback(null, buffer.readUInt8(index));
        readBufferBytes(buffer,callback,index+1);
    });
  } catch(e) {
     return process.nextTick(()=>{callback(e);});
  }

}
```

A must-notice thing about these functions is that I iterate the buffer as an array that on each position is contained 1 byte. Thus the index passed in `readUInt8` function is started from `0` and is increased by 1 on each iteration.